# WordPress shortcodes unautop doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp

I'm using the WordPress plugin Mailchimp on a customer's website and everything is great, except WordPress is killing the layout with its (hated and loved) wpautop feature.

I found several websites that discuss the same problem (wpautop messing up shortcode content). The websites then offered a few lines which shall make the shortcodes get generated after wpautop was called and everybody said it's working for them.

I uploaded these lines to my functions.php and ... nothing happened.

I have mailchimp running on another site, on which wpautop somehow doesn't mess up the code (without the code and without removing wpautop at all). None of the  functions.php files remove the wpautop feature for good.

The questions now is, what could be the reason that the code doesn't do anything?

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 99 );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop', 100 );
```

Answer (score -1):

Trying adding a priority to your `remove_filter()` like so:

`remove_filter("the_content", "wpautop", 30);`

Sometimes all you need is add priority to the different filters.

Also Im curious how `wpautop` messes with your shortcodes?

I have created numerous shortcodes and I never had an issue with the `wpautop` messing with my layout.